# How to retrieve data from AX query in SSRS data method

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, report, axapta

Everybody:

I just make a SSRS report with AX report tools. Sometimes we must get data from AX query. 
   I know how to add a dataset that use AX query, but not all dataset can from standard query, sometimes I must create business logic type dataset because I must process these data.

When I use business logic dataset, I had learned how to get data from SQL query, and know how to return dataTable to dataset. But I don’t know how to get data from user-defined AX query.

I can fetch data from SQL query with below codes:

```
 DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable(); // new table variable
    table = AxQuery.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM InventTable");
```

but I can’t build success with the codes below:
   remark:  I had created  a  `ventTableSRS` query in AX AOT.

```
DataTable ItemQueryTable = FIMCommonHelper.GetParameterDataTable(
        FIMAxQueries.InventTableSRS,
        new object[] { },
        new object[] { });
```

I found the class of `FIMaxQueries` don’t include my query(`InventTableSR`S). I try to found where the class of `FIMAxQueries` is, but I don’t get a result.

Could someone tell me how to write the codes, so that I can run an AX query and retrieve the result in SSRS report project business logic data method? The best way is to show me a sample codes.

Thanks you very much!

Spark

Answer (score 0):

EveryGuy:

I don't get the answer here but I search some solution , I paste some sample codes here.

```
  you can copy these codes into your dataset methods and modified it .
   -- begin 
    // get no parameter query
    #region get value of inventTableQuery
    DataTable ItemQueryTable = FIMCommonHelper.GetDataTable("InventTableSRS");


    /* // get parameter query
    DataTable ItemQueryTable = FIMCommonHelper.GetParameterDataTable(
        FIMAxQueries.InventTableSRS,
        new object[] { },
        new object[] { }); 
    */
    -- end
```

I had test it in my reports design. expert someone can use it.
Good luck!

Spark